# ErrorException Illegal string offset 'service_1' (View: form.blade.php)

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4

Getting ErrorException for an illegal string offset

```
<div class="control-group general">
    {{Form::label('content[service_1]', 'Service 1', array('class' => 'control-label'))}}
    <div class="controls">
        {{Form::text('content[service_1]', $page->options['service_1'])}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your **full** error message and show your **full** code! Also since you posted a question here you may want to include a actual question in your post. (The error can be in 3 different places or even more, and this is not a guessing game)

Comment: content[service_1] become a string... var_dump your content[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific error message means that `$page->options` is a string.  It looks like you're expecting it to be an array, so that's what you need to fix.

A little background on the actual error message: individual characters in a string can be accessed using array syntax, but the indexes are numeric, not associative.

```
$string = 'my string';
var_export($string[0]); // 'm'
var_export($string[1]); // 'y'
var_export($string['service_1']); // Illegal string offset 'service_1'
```